# Java - HTTPS Basic authentification with Apache httpclient

Tags: java, https, client, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to get some data (json data -> restful server) from a HTTPS server with basic authentification using the Apache httpclient. The SSL certificate is selfsigned.
The server is responding very well to a browser call and also when using curl.

However using the java Apache httpclient, that's another story.

***Client side :***

The **basic authentification is working** : the server sends me 401 errors if forget the authorization header or if I set the wrong base64 encoded login:password.

The **https/SSL part is working** : I am successfully getting data from online restful json server but sadly no way to find an online restful json server with basic authentification for testing purpose...

```
        try {

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
            try {
                httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.custom()
                                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                                        .build()
                                )
                        )
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                        .build();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://localhost:5050/getdata");
            getRequest.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic UBJ0aHVyOmFo0XElYHU=");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
```

Debugging is telling me :

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
```

True! It's not a valid HTTP response that I would like to get, it's a valid HTTP**S** response!

I guess that I am missing something...

Comment: "sadly no way to find an online restful json server with basic authentification" - Try: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd

Comment: Is this code snippet complete?  You don't know where you tried to read anything from the response or a stack trace that shows where the exception occurred

Comment: @Vasan. Tested with httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd, it's working perfectly...

Comment: @Alex, the exception is occuring on the last line of my code snippet : HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solved!***

The **error** was from the **server side** : my response did not include any headers....

httpclient seems to like well made responses from a server. That's not true for a browser or for curl : *garbage they can receive , display they will* !